# Problem aligning overlapping corner points in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

I am drawing some overlapping paths in Illustrator. However, some anchor points of different paths do not align correctly, they create some rugged corners. I tried to manually adjust the points with the direct selection tool but it is difficult to handle the corners.

Can anyone help me to fix the corners in the red circles?

[image: Problem corners]

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not the line join?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, yes, they are on different paths and each path is enclose already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your problem is with the points aligning, then you can use the alignment tool.

[image]

But if its about the behavior of your strokes overlapping, you can try experimenting with its corners.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is exactly what i am looking for, thank you very much for your tip, my path is fixed already. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, such a simple thing has been bothering me for a long time, though there is no answer for it. Although my main problem was having two anchor points after the intersection.