# Joining / Connecting Lines from the Pen Tool (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

So I made this shape using guides, shapes, and connecting all the lines with the Penn tool. This is what it looks like

[image: Shape]
Now because I used the pen tool not all the lines are connected, ex:
[image: Broken]

Because of this some of the corners are messed up, here is what they should look like
[image: Good Connected]

But some of them look like this because the lines are not one shape
[image: Broekn Connection]

I can't seem to get the "join" function to work when I select two of the points. Is there a good way to join the points together to make them one pen path or shape??

Comment: Expand first, then join. Do not expand stroke. Use the paintbucket to fill areas.

Comment: @Webster thanks I’ll give that a try, I want to keep the wireframe effect and not fill but thanks!

Comment: @Webster I expanded the shape but in the cases of the corners it still won't join them because they are not "endpoints" and when I convert the whole thing to a shape it gets like 4 out of 7

Comment: I'm sorry, make sure stroke is set to corners, expand (not stroke) then use pathfinder "Unite". That should join them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor points in Illustrator have a maximum of **two** connectors. That is essentially an "in" path and an "out" path. No anchor point can *ever* have more than 2 paths connected to it. You can't `Join` three paths to one anchor point. It's not possible.

With the above in mind, you can *never* `Join` anchors if there are more than 2 paths.`Join` works to take an anchor point with *one* path and *join* it to *another* anchor point with *one* path, resulting in a single anchor point with two paths.

Often for multiple anchors a better solution is to select both anchors and `Average` them `Object > Path > Average` and tick the `Both` option, to get multiple anchors to perfectly align. They won't be "joined" but they will be positioned precisely in the same location *appearing* as if they are one anchor even though they aren't. This is most often what I use when I need multiple anchors to be precisely positioned.

You may also get better results by switching to **Outline mode** (`Window > Outline`) and ensuring the two anchors are aligned.

Or rethink how shapes are built......

You can round corners as in this question: [Problem aligning overlapping corner points in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71617/problem-aligning-overlapping-corner-points-in-illustrator)

Or you can draw the outer shape, then add internal divisions as separate paths, as in this question: [How to join two overlapping non-end points that belong to two paths?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24994/how-to-join-two-overlapping-non-end-points-that-belong-to-two-paths)