# Issues with path fill in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: Here is the shape itself, just so you have a general reference]

Here is the shape itself, just so you have a general reference

[image: I created it with a path tool, but it ended up being two shapes, regardless, they seem to have identical points, the join function doesn't work on either corner]

I created it with a path tool, but it ended up being two shapes, regardless, they seem to have identical points, the join function doesn't work on either corner

[image: My actual issue is this - when attempting to fill in the shape, regardless of whether I group it or not, there is a hole in it.]

My actual issue is this - when attempting to fill in the shape, regardless of whether I group it or not, there is a hole in it.

I've tried joining, but it doesn't seem to work. Pathfinder creates a path along the same non-existent "edge" that gets filled out with fill.

What can I do to properly consolidate the shape?

Comment: There are supposed to be descriptions associated with the pictures, but I can't see them, hopefully you guys can.

Comment: I moved your image descriptions for you so they could be read by others.  (That areas is the alt attribute for web images). You may find it helpful to check here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99459/joining-connecting-lines-from-the-pen-tool-illustrator/99463#99463 Seems you may not understand what "join" means or limitations of paths/anchors in bezier drawing.

Comment: Thank you Scott

Answer (score 1):

Fills only work properly on closed paths. Your design contains some open paths.  Grouping won't make any difference. Joining might work if you were creating a closed path, but you can't join a path to another path in the middle of a path like that.  Also note this limitation is not specific to Illustrator, but all vector applications work similarly. It's a limitation of using vectors.

[image]

There are several way to work around this problem. Here are a couple.

1. You could use the Shape Builder tool to make closed paths, then apply fills to each object as normal.

[image]

2. Or you could select all the pieces and do *Object > Live Paint Make*, and use the Live Paint Bucket tool (K) to fill the pieces.

[image]

3. Another method would be to make closed paths which overlap. This is by far the simplest solution, and requires no fancy tools that are specific to Illustrator only.

[image]